Is there any way to export layers with the same layer name in Photoshop?
I am very new to Photoshop's powerful working mechanism. I am working on multiple layers having images in it. I want all to export as a JPEG format.

I am doing is, I am copying the layer name and File > Export > Save for web (legacy) > JPEG.

But I want all my layers to be exported one by one and with the same name. Since I have more than 110 layers with different names.
Is there any script or any way in Photoshop to achieve this?
Please see the screenshot below.


File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files... Does that work?

@Scott Thanks for replying, but No I tried that also, but it is taking the default name with some number on it
For ex.
000001_13_F.JPEG
000002_13_B.JPEG
So then I have to remove the initial numbers one by one accordingly.
I just want the layer name nothing else attached with it.

There are Finder/File Explorer tools to quickly batch rename things.  For me, I'd let Photoshop export hot o wants, then just batch rename in the Finder to remove any superfluous numbering.

I understood what you are saying, and I have tried that as well. It does not work when the file names have different values on each file.
This method only works when your files have having same names or numbers in it, so that you can find and replace them.
But if you are having files like 000001_ 000002_ 000003_ then this method won't work @Scott

My scenario is different here, I want to export 110 layers with 110 different names.
@Scott

Well,
I found my answer, and I am adding the solution here since it might help you in your case.
So the solution was
You have to make a small edit in Photoshops > Script > Export layers to Files.jsx
I followed a YouTube video and it worked in my case.

Video Link - https://youtu.be/477T3r2CcjU?si=K7-DYclAdzbufr4G

Find the line fileNameBody += "" + layerName; and delete the ""
Save the changes by going to File > Save
Copy and paste the file back into the Photoshop Scripts folder
Click Overwrite if prompted
Go to File > Export > Export Layers to Files

